# Remove Ecto from existing Phoenix project

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have an existing project built with default settings. Now I see that I dont really need Ecto for anything. I just want to remove all DB related events from the code.

Can someone guide me through the process ?

I have removed all mention of Ecto from mix.exs but I guess thats not enough

Update:

I found ecto mentioned in lib/api_test/repo.ex file. If I remove the line it gives the following error

```
=INFO REPORT==== 21-Jul-2016::12:43:30 ===
    application: logger
    exited: stopped
    type: temporary
** (Mix) Could not start application api_test: ApiTest.start(:normal, []) returned an error: shutdown: failed to start child: ApiTest.Repo
    ** (EXIT) an exception was raised:
        ** (UndefinedFunctionError) function ApiTest.Repo.start_link/0 is undefined or private
            (api_loc) ApiTest.Repo.start_link()
            (stdlib) supervisor.erl:365: :supervisor.do_start_child/2
            (stdlib) supervisor.erl:348: :supervisor.start_children/3
            (stdlib) supervisor.erl:314: :supervisor.init_children/2
            (stdlib) gen_server.erl:328: :gen_server.init_it/6
            (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:247: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
```

Comment: I will start removing `phoenix_ecto` from the deps and look where the compiler start complaining. The compiler where not complaining after deleting ecto from mix.exs ?

Comment: You could create a new phoenix project with the `--no-ecto` flag and then compare it to your existing one.

Comment: Do you still have a line such as `worker(ApiTest.Repo, args),` mentioned somewhere? See if Repo is still mentioned somewhere in your project.

Answer (score 16):

I think I have a good solution for you. I created two fresh Phoenix projects, one with Ecto, one with the `--no-ecto` flag (`mix phoenix.new --no-ecto my_app`). I then initialised a Git repo in the one with Ecto, added and commited everything and then deleted all files and replaced them with the ones from the project without Ecto.

The result is [this commit on GitHub](https://github.com/ospaarmann/remove_ecto_from_phoenix/commit/95f9f1c8c26c7a63f5563eb29491235bc64c41fb). I think there you find a very good starting point on what to change.

Comment: Did you mean you *...replaced them with the one **without** Ecto*?

Comment: this helped me a lot. Just follow the commit and delete everything that is marked in red and works like magic

Answer (score 4):

This can now be done with `mix ecto.drop -r MyApp.Repo` (where `MyApp` is the name of the application). See the guides for [ecto.drop](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Mix.Tasks.Ecto.Drop.html).

Additionally this could be done manually by deleting `MyApp.Repo` and the reference in `lib/my_app/application.ex` under the `start` function.

Answer (score 0):

Got it done.

Basically followed the documentation of Phoenix for including Ecto mentioned at https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/1.3.0-rc.2/ecto_models.html

Just did the reverse of whatever was mentioned in the document.